# Deterministic SIR metapopulation model and coupling behavior

Tags: python, numerics, differential-equations, reproducibility

**Context:**

I am trying to reproduce a figure from Keeling 2007 that illustrates time lags that can occur between the *peaks* (maximum) of the infected solutions for two subpopulations of a metapopulation model that uses deterministic $SIR$ equations (where $X=S$ and $Y=I$). The equations that model the subpopulation dynamics are defined below (Keeling 2007, pp. 237). Note that in the final equation, $Y_j$ is used instead of $X_j$. The book mistakenly uses $X_j$.

\begin{aligned}
  \frac{dX_i}{dt} &= \nu_i N_i - \lambda_i X_i - \mu_i X_i && \text{(1)} \newline
  \frac{dY_i}{dt} &= \lambda_i X_i - \gamma_i Y_i - \mu_i Y_i && \text{(2)} \newline
  \lambda_i       &= \beta_i \sum_{j=1}^{n} p_{ij} \frac{Y_j}{N_i} && \text{(3)}
\end{aligned}

Note that $p_{21}$ is an element of a matrix $p \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n}$ where $p_{ij}$ measures the relative strength of transmission (i.e., coupling) to subpopulation $i$ from subpopulation $j$ for $n=2$ subpopulations; $\nu$, $\mu$, $\gamma$, and $\beta$ are parameters of the model. Lastly, by time lag, I mean specifically

\begin{aligned}
  I_1     & \in \mathcal{R}^{T} \newline
  I_2     & \in \mathcal{R}^{T} \newline
  TimeLag(I_1, I_2) & := argmax(I_1) - argmax(I_2)
\end{aligned}

for $T$ timesteps used for numerical integration. Since no $T$ is specified in the figure, I just used $T=160$ where each timestep $t$ is a single day. Here is the original figure:

[image]

**Question:**

I am not as familiar with numerically solving differential equations that are vectors (i.e., $\frac{dX}{dt} = \langle \frac{dX_1}{dt}, \frac{dX_2}{dt}, ..., \frac{dX_n}{dt} \rangle$), so possibly I made a mistake in the implementation of the metapopulation model? Any insight would be appreciated.

*COMMENTS:* I am not trying to replicate the stochastic result in the figure, though I will have to try that later. The initial conditions for subpopulation 2 are not given in the figure in the book, but a previous section of the book describes that subpopulation 2's initial susceptible population $S(0)=1$ and there are no infected $I(0)=0$. I assume that the initial conditions are proportions since the figure states $S(0) = 1 - I(0)$, which implies that the subpopulation 1's size is $N_1 = 1$. I also assume that $N_1 = N_2 = 1$ and there are no births or deaths. I am not sure why $N_2=10^{5}$ is given at the end of description of the book figure.

*NOTE:* I receive no warnings during numerical integration, which leads me to believe that my implementation is off somewhere or that the authors are doing something that they don't tell the reader (see [this seasonal forcing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73884591/unable-to-reproduce-simple-figure-from-textbook-possible-numerical-instability) and [this bifurcation diagram code](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41994/python-bifurcation-diagram-of-seasonally-forced-epidemiological-models) for examples of attempts to reproduce other figures from this book)

**My Attempt**

My code produces the below figure. Note how as the coupling constant $p_{21}$ increases, the peak time of the infected population for subpopulation 1 becomes greater than the peak time of the infected population for subpopulation 2. This directly contradicts the figure in the book.

[image]

To illustrate that the infected solution outputs are "reasonable" looking, I've included one more figure below. I annotate the x-coordinate (time) for the maximums (peaks) of the infected populations for each subpopulation. This should help illustrate what I mean by *peaks* of infected solutions. The difference between these peak times is plotted in the figures above (e.g., for $p_{21}=1.0e-06$ the time lag is $46 - 85 = -39$).

[image]

**Minimal Code to Reproduce My Attempt**

```py
from typing import List, Union

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import ndarray
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def metapopulation_model(
    y: Union[List, ndarray], 
    t: float, 
    n_subpops: int, 
    betas: Union[List, ndarray], 
    gammas: Union[List, ndarray], 
    nus: Union[List, ndarray], 
    mus: Union[List, ndarray], 
    subpop_sizes: Union[List, ndarray], 
    p_matrix: Union[List[List], ndarray]):
    """Deterministic metapopulation model with SIR equations."""

    # Array for diff eqs for state vars --> 2 state vars times population size
    dydt = np.zeros((2*n_subpops)) 

    # Extract the state vars for the current timestep
    x_vector = y[0: n_subpops]
    y_vector = y[n_subpops: ]

    # Compute the forces of infection given the conditions
    # This is equation (3) in the **Context** section of this post
    lambdas = []
    for i in range(n_subpops):
        lambda_i = betas[i]*np.sum(p_matrix[i, :]*y_vector/subpop_sizes[i])
        lambdas.append(lambda_i)

    for i in range(n_subpops):

        # update x variables
        # This is equation (1) in the **Context** section of this post
        dydt[i] = nus[i]*subpop_sizes[i] - lambdas[i]*x_vector[i] - mus[i]*x_vector[i]

        # Update y variables
        # This is equation (2) in the **Context** section of this post
        dydt[i+n_subpops] = lambdas[i]*x_vector[i] \
            - gammas[i]*y_vector[i] - mus[i]*y_vector[i]

    # Vector whose elements [0: n_subpops] are the solution
    # for the susceptibles in each subpopulation
    # and elements [n_subpops: ] are the solution for the infected
    # in each subpopulation 
    return dydt


def lag(pop_1_infected: List, pop_2_infected: List):
    """Compute delay between the peak of epidemics in two populations.

    This is the TimeLag function in the **Context** section of this post. 
    """

    peak_pop_1_infected_ix = np.argmax(pop_1_infected)
    peak_pop_2_infected_ix = np.argmax(pop_2_infected)
    return peak_pop_1_infected_ix - peak_pop_2_infected_ix

# Define initial conditions
# NOTE: POSSIBLE ISSUE HERE????
N = 1
I0 = 1e-5
S0 = 1 - I0
y0 = [S0, N, I0, 0.0]  # [X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2]

# Define parameters
n_subpops = 2
betas = np.array([0.3571 for i in range(n_subpops)])
gammas = np.array([1/14 for i in range(n_subpops)])
nus = np.array([0 for i in range(n_subpops)])
mus = np.array([0 for i in range(n_subpops)])
subpop_sizes = np.array([N for i in range(n_subpops)])

# Define Time steps
n_days = 160
t_range = np.arange(0, n_days+1)

# Define different coupling constants p_21
couplings = np.array([1e-6, 1e-4, 1e-2, 1e0])

# track lag of time between infected solutions in population 1 and population 2
lags = []

# Track infected solutions for pop1 and pop 2
# Used for visualizing time lag
infected_solutions_at_coupling = np.zeros((len(couplings), len(t_range), 2))

# Initialize the p_matrix
# NOTE: POSSIBLE ISSUE HERE????
p_matrix = np.zeros((n_subpops, n_subpops))
np.fill_diagonal(p_matrix, val=1)

# Compute solutions using different coupling constants
for coupling_ix, coupling in enumerate(couplings):
    
    # Set the coupling constant for ij = 21 = 10
    p_matrix[1][0] = coupling

    # Compute solutions 
    sols = odeint(
        func=metapopulation_model,
        y0=y0,
        t=t_range,
        args=(n_subpops, betas, gammas, nus, mus, subpop_sizes, p_matrix))

    # Extract infected solutions for the different populations
    # sols:
    #   0      1     2      3
    #   X_1    X_2   Y_1    Y_2
    # t ...    ...   ...    ...
    # 0 ...    ...   ...    ... 
    # 1 ...    ...   ...    ...
    # .........................
    pop_1_infected = sols[:, 2]
    pop_2_infected = sols[:, 3]

    # Compute the lag between the two infected peaks
    lag_ = lag(
        pop_1_infected=pop_1_infected, pop_2_infected=pop_2_infected)

    # Track infected soultions at this coupling value
    infected_solutions_at_coupling[coupling_ix, :, 0] = pop_1_infected
    infected_solutions_at_coupling[coupling_ix, :, 1] = pop_2_infected

    # Track the lag
    lags.append(lag_)

# Plot the result
couplings_as_strs = [f'{i:.1e}' for i in couplings]  # for spacing reasons
plt.xlabel(r'$p_{21}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$TimeLag(I_1, I_2) := argmax(I_1) - argmax(I_2)$')
plt.title('Attempt to Reproduce Part of Figure 7.1: Keeling 2007')
plt.plot(couplings_as_strs, lags, '.--')
```

Comment: The model includes birth $\nu_iN_i$ and general death terms $\mu_iX_i$, $\mu_iY_i$. This suggests that the total population $N_i$ is also variable. Is that addressed somewhere?

Comment: The equations would be (mostly) insensitive to the scale of $N_i$ if the coupling term were $λ_i=β_i\sum_j\frac{Y_j}{N_j}$, so that it would be permissible to combine densities in one part with population numbers in the other.

Comment: In the figure and in my code, I $mu$ and $nu$ are $0$ for all subpopulations where $N_i$ is the $i^{th}$ subpopulation. I believe the book mentions $N_j$ is also an option for the definition of $\lambda_i$. In any case, $N_i$ is the `subpop_sizes` variable in my code and is the same for both subpopulations as well as constant since the birth and death rate are not included.

Comment: The book states "The equation above contains $N_i$ in the denominator, which reflects the implicit assumption that transmission takes place in population $i$,
presumably resulting from the movement of an infectious individual from population $j$. 
Alternatively, the assumption that transmission is due to a susceptible individual from
population $i$ picking up the infection during a temporary visit to population $j$ would be
incorporated by placing $N_j$ in the denominator. "

Comment: I changed $N_i$ in the denominator to $N_j$. No change occurs for the outputs. I'm definitely uncertain about the initial conditions and the way that the coupling matrix $p$ is defined. The initial conditions for population 1 are provided, but they are not provided for population 2, and the specification of $N_2$ in the fig is suspect to me. I currently define the coupling matrix $p$ as $p=\langle 1, 0, p_{21}, 1 \rangle$ (this is flattened for this question obviously), then $p_{21}$ is varied. Since $p_{12}=0$, this implies that the strength of transmission to pop 1 from pop 2 is negligible.

Comment: You can shorten some code lines with `lambdas = (betas/subpop_sizes)*(p_matrix @ y_values)` for the original interpretation and `lambdas = betas*(p_matrix @ (y_values/subpop_sizes))` for the modified interpretation. The same way you can eliminate the loop for `dydt` using that `*` on numpy arrays (why the List type?) is component-wise multiplication. // I still do not see anything wrong in your code.

Comment: I use the list type to help to denote dimensionality actually, ndarrays are what's passed as args to the func. I edited my code to reflect this type annotation. I have also updated the params to be ndarrays to support those cleaner looking operations you suggested.

Comment: With regard to nothing being wrong with my code, that may be the case. As you know from previous posts, this author sometimes makes decisions that are not obvious (at least for a student) to implement. My current figure is sufficient since the assignment puts no expectations on the students to replicate figures from the textbook, I just prefer to do it to verify my implementations.

Comment: The first plot would be an exact looking replication if you switched the sign of the y axis, that is, computed $argmax(I_2)-argmax(I_1)$.

Comment: Yes!! I realized that about 2 minutes ago! Thank you for your insight as always. Hopefully, this is the correct logic.

Comment: Usually if speaking of a lag from event 1 to event 2 it is meant as $T_2=T_1+lag$.

Comment: @JaredFrazier: Nice use of type annotations! I'd suggest being more opinionated and choosing one of `Union[List, ndarray]` rather than using the `Union`. Also: `List` is actually a generic type, so you can give your type checking tools more to work with by writing `List[float]`.

Comment: @Richard Thanks! When I write just for myself, I will try to be specific and annotate ndarray for most things and then add in the function description what shapes that ndarray might take on, but for the sake of brevity in the code example I just used the `List` as a place holder to show that "hey, this ndarray is 1D". You're right though that `List[float]` would be more descriptive. Maybe there is a better way to annotate ndarray shapes in the function parameters? I am not aware of something in the `typing` library for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My implementation approximately reproduces the figure if I reverse the terms of the time lag calculation. Per comments, time lag is normally computed as $T_2 = T_1 + lag$, therefore $lag = T_2 - T_1$. I misinterpreted the order of this calculation based on the original figure, which labels the y-axis "population 1 and population 2"

```py
def lag(pop_1_infected: List, pop_2_infected: List):
    """Compute delay between the peak of epidemics in two populations."""

    peak_pop_1_infected_ix = np.argmax(pop_1_infected)
    peak_pop_2_infected_ix = np.argmax(pop_2_infected)

    # CHANGED THE ORDER OF THIS CALCULATION
    return peak_pop_2_infected_ix - peak_pop_1_infected_ix
```

[image]